# How to detect power save mode in Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

Default `set timer for ...` application somehow detects power save mode. 
It changes notification text accordinly.

- Full power: 1:29:15
- Power save: 1hr, 29 min

How can we detect power save mode in Android Wear and change our notifications appropriately?

[image: Focused screen] [image: Power save mode]

Answer (score 1):

Pure speculation, but try using what's found here. It works for watch faces, so it might be relevant for system wide: http://gist.github.com/PomepuyN/cdd821eca163a3279de2

Comment: I just tested in my Application ("extends Service") - and it works great! In other words, not a Watch Face, but a normal App. Thank you.

Comment: Follow-up. I find that sometimes it sends duplicate events and/or skips an event. Haven't had time to delve into why.